# How to specify PTR for Azure PublicIP with Terraform

Tags: dns, terraform-provider-azure

I am setting up an alias record in an Azure-hosted DNS zone to point to the public (egress) IP of a K8s cluster, like this:

```
data "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
    name                = "example.com"
}

locals {
    egress_id             = tolist(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.network_profile.0.load_balancer_profile.0.effective_outbound_ips)[0]
    egress_name           = reverse(split("/", local.egress_id))[0]
    egress_resource_group = reverse(split("/", local.egress_id))[4]
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "k8s" {
    name                = var.dns_prefix
    zone_name           = data.azurerm_dns_zone.example.name
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_dns_zone.example.resource_group_name
    ttl                 = 300
    target_resource_id  = local.egress_id
}

output "ptr_command" {
    value = "az network public-ip update --name ${local.egress_name} --resource-group ${local.egress_resource_group} --reverse-fqdn ${var.dns_prefix}.example.com --dns-name ${var.dns_prefix}-${local.egress_name}"
}
```

This works, and (just to prove that it works) I can also add a PTR record for reverse lookup with the explicit API command produced by the output block -- but can I get terraform to do that as part of apply? (One problem is that it would have to happen after the creation of the A record since Azure will check that it points at the correct IP).

(A k8s egress does not need a PTR record, I hear you say, but something like an outgoing SMTP server does need correct reverse lookup).

Comment: I suppose I could write up something like an azurerm_dns_public_ip_reverse resource type that would depend on the azurerm_dns_a_record resource and take the PublicIP to modify from the target_resource_id attribute. It would still need to come up with a DNS label for the dns-name of the PublicIP, since Azure requires that and you can't give it an FQDN -- maybe escape the FQDN of the A record somehow to avoid collisions. (I got a collision just using the dns_prefix, somebody else had the same idea it seems and you have to be unique within the Azure location).

Comment: You could post your useful comment as an answer if you have found it.

Comment: @Nancy Xiong, As long as I haven't actually written the code, I don't think it works as an answer.

Comment: So I just let the ansible playbook do it, right? Wrong! azure_rm_publicipaddress doesn't seem to be able to set the reverse_fqdn value, though it will show it in the return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to add a `local-exec` provisioner to the DNS record resource -- but one that modifies the public IP using an explicit CLI command. Not a good solution because it is not where you'd look, but at least the ordering is right. Also I think the way I do it only works if you did `az login` to give Terraform access to your Azure account, though I'm sure you can configure `az` to use the same credentials as Terraform in other cases.

Here is a worked example with an explicit `azurerm_public_ip` resource, illustrating another Catch 22: On next apply, Terraform will see the `reverse_fqdn` attribute and attempt to remove it, unless you tell it that it's OK. (In the OP, the public IP was created by an `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource and Terraform does not store its full state).

```
data "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
        name                = "example.com"
}

resource "random_id" "domain_label" {
        byte_length = 31 # 62 hex digits.
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
        lifecycle {
                # reverse_fqdn can only be set after a DNS record has
                # been created, so we do it in a provisioner there.
                # Do not try to change it back, please.
                ignore_changes = [reverse_fqdn]
        }

        name = "example"
        location = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
        resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
        allocation_method = "Static"
        domain_name_label = "x${random_id.domain_label.hex}"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "example" {
        name                = "example"
        zone_name           = data.azurerm_dns_zone.example.name
        resource_group_name = data.azurerm_dns_zone.example.resource_group_name
        ttl                 = 300
        target_resource_id  = azurerm_public_ip.example.id

        provisioner "local-exec" {
                command = "az network public-ip update --name ${azurerm_public_ip.example.name} --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.example.name} --reverse-fqdn example.example.com"
        }
}
```

I still have a problem that the `target_resource_id` attribute on the A record seems to disappear if Terraform replaces the VM that is using the network interface that the public IP is associated with. But another apply solves that.

Comment: Full disclosure: I got tired of the extra apply to put back the `target_resource_id` every time Terraform recreates the VM (I'm testing cloud-init stuff so that happens a lot), so now I'm using a CNAME record instead. The PTR record thing still works fine, though,  Azure will follow CNAMEs when it checks to see if the `reverse_fqdn` is legit.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when I skip explicit `reverse_fqdn` and workaround with `azurerm_dns_a_record`...

```
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = local.subdomain
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip_prefix" "example" {
    name                = local.aks_public_ip_prefix_name
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

    prefix_length = 31

    tags = {
        environment = "Production"
    }
}



resource "azurerm_public_ip" "aks_ingress" {
    name                = local.aks_public_ip_name
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    allocation_method   = "Static"
    sku = "Standard"
    domain_name_label = local.subdomain_prefix

    public_ip_prefix_id = azurerm_public_ip_prefix.example.id
    tags = {
        environment = "Production"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "@"
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ttl                 = 300
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_public_ip.aks_ingress.id
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAKUa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhzRv.png)